# Problem with reschedule check in check-mk

Tags: check-mk

please help me. when I create a check in the mrpe.cfg and add a parameter (interval=200), I do not have the ability to use “reschedule check”. is there any way to fix it? thank you in advance.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jokUi.png)

Answer (score 0):

Well, you configured a check to run cached, so there is no active rescheduling of that service. You have to wait for the caching interval to expire. Then the agent will deliver new data.